# What is the logic behind the control statement 'if((i+j) & 1)'?

Tags: c, arrays, char

This program declares an 8x8 character array and then uses a loop to store the following data into the array(one character per array element). Then it prints this array to the screen:

BRBRBRBR

RBRBRBRB

BRBRBRBR

RBRBRBRB

BRBRBRBR

RBRBRBRB

BRBRBRBR

RBRBRBRB

The program works fine. However, I am having trouble understanding the logic behind the if statement:

```
if((i+j) & 1)
```

I don't understand how if adding i + j 'and' 1 is true set array to 'R' else set it to 'B'. This might have a rather obvious answer, but I am new to C. Can someone help clarify why this program works with this logic? Thank You!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    char letter[8][8];
    for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<8; j++) {
            //This if-statement
            if ((i+j) & 1)
                letter[i][j] = 'R';
            else 
                letter[i][j] = 'B';
            printf("%c" , letter[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `&` is bitwise AND operator. The `a & 1` results into `1` (logical "true") when least significant bit of `a` is set. In other words, when `a` is an odd number or `0` (logical "false") when number is even.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Thank You.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: `(i+j)&1` == `(i^j)&1` == `(i&1) ^ (j&1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(i+j) & 1` will evaluate to `true` when `i+j` is odd and `false` when `i+j` is even.

The `&` in that expression is the bitwise AND operator, not the logical AND operator.

The code would be so much more readable if written as:

```
int is_odd(int n)
{
   return ((n&1) == 1);
}

...

if ( is_odd(i+j) )
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a pattern here - the last bit of the value is constantly flipped:

```
i = 0, j = 0 --> i + j = 0 --> 2'b00
i = 0, j = 1 --> i + j = 1 --> 2'b01
i = 0, j = 2 --> i + j = 2 --> 2'b10
...and so on
```

The `&` operator then does a bit-wise `and` operation on the bits of the value:

```
//this evaluates to false, and 'B' is printed
2'b00 & 1 == 2'b00 & 2'b01 == 2'b(0&0)(0&1) == 2'b00 
//this evaluates to true, and 'R' is printed
2'b01 & 1 == 2'b01 & 2'b01 == 2'b(0&0)(1&1) == 2'b01
```